# how to get env variable in controller or other classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration

I have this custom ConfigurationService, everything was working fine, but I need to load settings based on env now. So to do that I have this method `LoadAppSettings`

```
public class ConfigurationService : IConfigurationService
    {

        public IConfigurationRoot LoadAppSettings(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            try
            {
                var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(_basePath)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true) //for azure functions
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

                return config;
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

When calling this method from other places, like controller, how can I access current env?

```
IConfigurationRoot Config
    {
        get
        {
            if (_config == null)
            {
                _config = ConfigurationService.LoadAppSettings(ENV ?);
            }
            return _config;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You would need to explicitly inject `IHostingEnvironment` into where that method is used.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must inject `IHostingEnvironment` interface in `contractor` controller like this.

```cs
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }
}
```

then pass the `IHostingEnvironment` to method

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //test
    _config = ConfigurationService.LoadAppSettings(_hostingEnvironment);
    return Ok();
}
```

**Update**

Another way is using `IOptions<>`

in this case you must register an class that showing environment variable like this

```cs
public class AppSettings
{
    public string Environment { get; set; }
}
```

register class in `ConfigureServices` method and get`Environment` from `CurrentEnvironment.EnvironmentName`

```cs
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
private Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment CurrentEnvironment { get; set; }
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    CurrentEnvironment = env;
}
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(a => new AppSettings { Environment = CurrentEnvironment.EnvironmentName });
}
```

then in your controller inject `IOption<AppSettings>` instead of `IHostingEnvironment` and change `LoadAppSettings(IHostingEnvironment env)` to `LoadAppSettings(AppSettings appSettings)`

Controller

```cs
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;
    public HomeController(IOptions<AppSettings> options)
    {
        _appSettings = options.Value;
    }
}
```

Action

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //test
    _config = ConfigurationService.LoadAppSettings(_appSettings);
    return Ok();
}
```

and finally change the  `LoadAppSettings` method to this

```cs
public IConfigurationRoot LoadAppSettings(AppSettings env)
{
    try
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(_basePath)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true) //for azure functions
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

        return config;
    }
    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
    {
         return null;
    }
```

Comment: This is not a best practice. Applications should only load what they need when running. You don't need to load all settings and pick those you want at runtime.

Comment: @CodeNotFound i updated my answer. and this way is better. thanks for guidance